# Java oop - inheritance

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm copy and paste this code from the website that I'm working on.

```
 * A Line composes of two Points - a begin point and an end point.
 */
 public class Line {
// The private instance variables
Point begin, end;   // Object members - instances of the Point class

// Constructors
public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
   begin = new Point(x1, y1);  // Construct the instances declared
   end   = new Point(x2, y2);
}
public Line(Point begin, Point end) {
   this.begin = begin;  // The caller constructed the instances
   this.end   = end;
}

// The public getter and setter for the private instance variables
public Point getBegin() {
   return begin;
}
public Point getEnd() {
   return end;
}
public void setBegin(Point begin) {
   this.begin = begin;
}
public void setEnd(Point end) {
   this.end = end;
}

public int getBeginX() {
   return begin.getX();  // Point's getX()
}
public void setBeginX(int x) {
   begin.setX(x);  // Point's setX()
}
public int getBeginY() {
   return begin.getY();  // Point's getY()
}
public void setBeginY(int y) {
   begin.setY(y);  // Point's setY()
}
public int[] getBeginXY() {
   return begin.getXY();  // Point's getXY()
}
public void setBeginXY(int x, int y) {
   begin.setXY(x, y);  // Point's setXY()
}
public int getEndX() {
   return end.getX();  // Point's getX()
}
public void setEndX(int x) {
   end.setX(x);  // Point's setX()
}
public int getEndY() {
   return end.getY();  // Point's getY()
}
public void setEndY(int y) {
   end.setY(y);  // Point's setY()
}
public int[] getEndXY() {
   return end.getXY();  // Point's getXY()
}
public void setEndXY(int x, int y) {
   end.setXY(x, y);  // Point's setXY()
}

// The toString() describe itself
public String toString() {
   return "Line[begin=" + begin + ",end=" + end + "]";
         // Invoke begin.toString() and end.toString()
}

public double getLength() {
    return begin.distance(end);  // Point's distance()
   }
}
```

So here we have to classes public class Point and public class Line

in the first constructor Public line ....
so as we see here we contruct the class , it's a constructor and there is nothing wrong about how it used or anything wrong about it's logic doesn't exist

but there is also this method public Point... this is not the Point class so how come we can use this method here.

I kinda figured that out since Point acts like some sort of areturn type since in that method we wan't to get begin and begin is a point, an object defined udner the point class. so i get that, that's the only way we can get begin. But once we do

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Line l1 = new Line(new Point(7,8), new Point(2,5));
```

The constructor starts acting here. So at the end new line is formed. but in the constructor there is no such thing as

```
   return line;
```

or is there return line; but we can't see it? I don't know. 
However in the method which takes return type as Point there is a

```
  return point;
```

But no

```
 return x;
```

in constructors, I'm having trouble understanding the logic here.

and by the way we can benefit from this method

```
 public Point getBegin() {
  return begin;
 }
```

in this way :

```
 l1.getBegin().SOMEPOINTMETHOD;
```

but what if we don't do such a thing and just initiate

```
 l1.getBegin();
```

what kind of output will we get? I know the output type is going to point, but since point is an object and since we didnt input the instances of the object we won't get anything right? Eclipse gives kind of a strange error in this case.

I know it's been so long but I'm just trying to understand the logic here, sorry if I'm too "DUMMY" and please don't judge right away -.- (Same case for off-topicing this topic)

Comment: but there are such things as return types, so `public Point xxx` is actually a normal method and not a constructor. Just like a method `public int getSize() {...}` would be a casual method with the return type `int`.

Comment: "but in the constructor there is no such thing as return line;" - Constructors doesn't have return type. Think it this way, since constructor already creates an instance of that class you don't need an explicit return.

Comment: If I were you I'd first go over some of these basic Java readings such as this one > https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html and this one, it's also about points :) > https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8 Just trust me, if you're serious about learning Java, start reading, there's lots of reading to do no matter how good you get at it so you might as well start fresh :)!

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are a special kind of (class bound) method that implicitly create an instance of the class type. You'll have to use the `new` keyword to retrieve this instance.

If you use a method with a non-void `Returntype`, the method body will execute and in the end, it will return an object of type `Returntype`. It's up to you (e.g. your program) to do something with the returned object, but you can as well just ignore it.

And, above all: This doesn't have anything to do with inheritance!

Comment: Thanks even though the title of my topic is wrong, instead of all these people around here you ignored that and helped out. thank you :)